# ManyToMany field constraints in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models

This is a general database question that is not specific to Django. Since I'm using Django, I am asking it in this context. Suppose I have three models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ModelB(models.Model)
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ModelC(models.Model)
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bs = models.ManyToManyField(ModelB, blank=True)
```

I would like `ModelC` to have a link to many `ModelB`s. I would like there to be a constraint that only allows `ModelC` to have a `ModelB` if they share a common `ModelA`. Is there a way to architect this properly at the database level or should this be done logically in other parts of the system?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to enforce that at the database level, but to enforce it in application code, you can use the `m2m_changed` signal (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) in order to make this check before adding anything to your many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Let me know if you need any clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Ross Mechanic, I solved it using that method. For anyone else with the same question, I solved it with the following:

```
def bs_changed(**kwargs):
    """
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    if kwargs['action'] != 'pre_add':
        return

    if kwargs['reverse']:
        b = kwargs['instance']
        cs = kwargs['model'].objects.filter(id__in=kwargs['pk_set'])
        for c in cs:
            if b.a != c.a:
                kwargs['pk_set'].remove(c.id)
    else:
        c = kwargs['instance']
        bs = kwargs['model'].objects.filter(id__in=kwargs['pk_set'])
        for b in bs:
            if b.a != c.a:
                kwargs['pk_set'].remove(b.id)


m2m_changed.connect(bs_changed, sender=ModelC.members.through)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of Ross Mechanic, I would recommend to add a condition to the action given by the `m2m_changed`. Otherwise you would have an error trying to change it in the django admin page.
Like

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=ModelC.bs.through)
def constraints_on_bs(sender, **kwargs):
    action = kwargs.get('action', None)
    if 'post' in action and error:
        raise ValidationError('Error with the relation m2m')
```